# What to do if color values go above 1?

Tags: game-physics, raytracing

I am working on a raytracer and when adding different colors like from lights,
reflected and refracted light, I get values above 1 and then I need to clamp.
But clamping is probably not correct? Maybe I should handle this in other way?

Comment: Camera chips usually clamp the values (sun is white, without any detail). HDR cameras store the real values (floating point number), it can be any number. You can also set lower "exposure" - multiply values by 0<k<1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error, it's an effect called saturation, or maybe overexposure. It happens in film and digital cameras, and in your eye, as well. The issue is simply that you've got so much light energy reaching your photoreceptor (in the case of an eye, or CCD in a digital camera, or photosensitive compound in a film camera) that the receptor is saturated to it's maximum output value. In other words, you can keep dumping more energy into it, but the receptor won't be able to output any stronger signal, so it will look the same. So the simple solution is to simply saturate all color values at 1.0, which mimics what happens in a real photoreceptor.

Of course, when this happens in your eye, your pupils constrict so not as much light gets in, and when a photographer has an overexposed shot, they might reduce the aperture, or the exposure time for the same reason. You can do the same in your renderer by simply dividing the color values at every pixel by a fixed amount. This is analogous to constricting the pupil or limiting the exposure time to reduce the amount of light energy that reaches each receptor. After doing so, you will still need to clamp any values that remain greater than 1 (or whatever your maximum color value is).

Of course you can store very large numerical color values using double precision floating point, or arbitrarily large numerical values using BigInts, for instance. But sooner or later, you need to actually produce this image in "real life": via a printer, or on a monitor, or store it to a standard image format like PNG. Whatever mechanism you use, there will be a limited range of output values that can be produced, and you'll need to fit your colors into that range. You can use either technique I described for doing this: you can simply clamp anything outside the available range, or you can scale all the values by a fixed amount so that all the values fit into the range. In the former case, you will get clipping in the image, meaning you will loose detail anywhere the light is very bright. In the latter case, you will experience a loss of contrast where ever the color-values are already close together, because scaling them down will bring them even closer together. Generally, you will want to apply both techniques to limit the two different problems. You could attempt to analyze the statistics of the image and decide algorithmically how to adjust it, but I'm not really sure what that would look like. The alternative is to adjust it manually through trial and error (presumably with lower quality renderings so each trial doesn't take as long).

Answer (score 2):

No, no, no, don't clamp. There is no maximum light intensity or radiance value in the real world. Exactly what physical process do you think would correspond to clamping the light value?

The only time clamping should even come into play is if you are saving your final pixels to a non-HDR image format (e.g., 8 bit integer pixels) or displaying on a monitor.  And then, you should still consider some kind of tone mapping or smooth roll-off to simulate film response rather than a hard clamp. But better is to save the images in a HDR format (i.e. floating point, such as 16 or 32 bit float OpenEXR files), and leave the tone mapping (reduction to limited dynamic range) to the display program.

Comment: Any real world optical device will saturate eventually. Each rod and cone in your eye can only output so much signal strength to the optical nerve, a CCD in a digital camera will eventually reach saturation, and whatever photoreactive compounds are use in film will eventually absorb so much light energy that they can no longer change in response. It might not be a hard cutoff, more of a roll off as you suggest, but it will have a maximum value; this is what causes clipping effects in photography. The best solution is attenuate all your values by a constant factor, and then clip if necessary.

Comment: I guess the original question was somewhat ambiguous. You could justify some kind of attenuation, roll-off, or clipping when saving the image, but not in any intermediate calculations like the reflected radiance from some surface. You certainly don't want to clamp to 1 for any lighting calculation, anywhere in the ray tracer, that happens to return a value >1.